# Select all users where the last event is of type X

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am working with Symfony2 and Doctrine. My model includes users, that have transactions, and these transactions have some events with a date. So I have an entity class `Users`, an entity class `Transactions` and an entity class `Events`. Each Event has a field `date` and a field `event_type`: How would I properly select all users where the last registered event of any transaction is of type `X`? (event_type is an integer)

I hope this was understandable,
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inside a controller using symfony 2.3+. You could use the doctrine query builder. Something like:

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('NamespacedBundle:Users')
    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->leftJoin('u.transactions','t')
    ->leftJoin('t.events','e')
    ->where('e.event_type = :eventType')
    ->andWhere('t.status = :transStatus')
    ->orderBy('e.date','DESC')
    ->setParameter('eventType',$eventType)
    //$eventType would be your integer to look for

    ->setParameter('transStatus','pending')
    //You would set this to whatever you are using to indicate non completed transactions

    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

This should give you a list of all users who have transactions that have events of event_type X. You could refine this more to restrict it to certain dates.

Keep in mind that the associations may not match exactly what is in your entity and may need to be adjusted, I took best guesses.

Comment: How would you add the condition that there is no newer event for a given transaction? Imagine one event to be submitted, and then the next one might be success and I'm looking for all users with transactions that have been submitted but that haven't been successful yet.

Comment: You would order the results by `e.date DESC` so that all the latest events are on top